# Unable to connect to MongoDB cloud by following code. I need to know whats wrong with this code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am unable to connect to cloud mongodb with the following code. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this code?
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//db config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

//Connect to mongo
mongoose
.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started on port ${port}'));
```

Comment: Try ```mongoose.connect('mongodb://<database username>:<password>@ds028559.mlab.com:28559/clzmate');```  to connect.

Comment: I am getting   this error, I think the problem is not in the code, they are unable to connect for some reason. Errorname: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Comment: can you show what you are getting in db?

Comment: db string:mongodb+srv://tanvirgeek:tanvirscc124867@mernshopping-yq3va.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple steps you should follow to be able to connect Mongo DB so first make sure that you created an account plus connecting to a cluster, while creating it you'll be provided with enough info to create a cluster take your time and read.

after doing that the code is very simple:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://[ACCOUNT NAME]:[PASSWORD]@cluster0-sxlgp.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true }
);
```

replace ACCOUNTNAME and PASSWORD with info you provided when you created your MongoDB account

This can be found in their documentation try taking your time reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting  this error, I think the problem is not in the code, I did exactly as the you said. Error name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code looks good the error you are getting TransientTransactionError is temporary please use events to handle your connection result

```
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongooose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('db connection success');
});
mongooose.connection.on('err', (err) => {
    console.log('db connection failed');
});
```

Comment: Thank You, Will the error be vanished automatically?